# How to get window opened/closed/minimized messages from a native app?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

It's tough to write a good title for this one.

I'm working on a WPF application which needs to know about the existence of all other open windows on the system. I'm able to do this by calling the native EnumWindows method just fine, and I can call other native methods to filter out just the windows I'm interested in. This works well.

The problem I'm having is that I want to know when a window is opened or closed (and, ideally, minimized). I can do this by polling with EnumWindows, but I'm finding that to be pretty slow, even if I push it off to another thread.

Is there a better way to get notifications of window opened/closed/minimized? Keep in mind that my knowledge of non-managed code is pretty limited.

Comment: Impossible? From here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework. To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.

Comment: Some progress here: http://pastebin.com/1q3qj5iY

If pass the current thread id, I do get messages when the application windows is focused and blurred, but I need messages from *all* windows. Passing 0 for the thread id to get all messages causes SetWindowsHookEx to return null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows hook for this type of thing.

Basically once setup your hook, your callback will be called whenever the messages you're interested get called.

There is a good example on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx) for setting global system wide hooks with C# code.
Note: There is a unmanaged c++ component to this project, but you don't need to work with it directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into that. I can at least get the sample running. It looks like it only supports mouse/keyboard events out of the box, and it's unclear whether I can extend it to get the messages I need. Will look further...

Comment: Looks like this is a no-go. Only mouse and keyboard hooks are implemented in the library, and extending it requires digging into the C++. Even if I were brave enough to do that, I can't get the project to run from source. Something about the managed call SetUserHookCallback not matching the native signature, but I can't even find any documentation on that method.

Comment: @Josh Santangelo: Yes running the demo doesn't require you to go into the C++ but to do what you want to do you would have to.  You would use that project as a starting point.  It's not trivial but very doable.

Comment: I skipped that demo, but made some progress. Still can't do a global hook, though: http://pastebin.com/1q3qj5iY

Answer (score 1):

WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING Message

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am using that to get all the windows at application startup, but it is too slow to use to catch changes in the window list at runtime.

Comment: How about WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING Message?

Comment: I'm able to get window messages from the current process, but not from the OS as a whole. Example here: http://pastebin.com/1q3qj5iY