# Desktop window monitoring with C#

Tags: c#, windows, monitoring

How can I monitor whether desktop windows have opened or closed? But I would like to avoid 'polling with EnumWindows every second and compare the results'.

For clarity

- not monitoring starting/exiting of processes, I really mean windows.

As a partial solution, it would suffice if I were notified of window changes to a particular process.

Comment: Do you mean explore.exe started and existed or killed or crashed? What is "*polling with EnumWindow*"?

Comment: The only way to avoid polling would be to hook events in the operating system, not something I'd consider lightly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get window opened/closed/minimized messages from a native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555743/how-to-get-window-opened-closed-minimized-messages-from-a-native-app) and [SetWinEventHook to catch a global destroyed process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628365/setwineventhook-to-catch-a-global-destroyed-process)

Comment: @OlivierRogier thx. the CodeProject solution looks promising, but is from 2005. I will test this out.

Comment: @OlivierRogier for the CodeProject  a) I can not compile the vcproj. missing a header file b) there are only mouse and keyboard hooks. c:) there must be a 32bit and 64bit dll, as far as I have understood the hook concept d) i have no glue of c++ development.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public List<String> GetOpenWindows()
    {
        List<String> OpenWindows = new List<string>();
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] Processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

        for (int i = 0; i < Processes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Processes[i].MainWindowTitle != "")
            {
                OpenWindows.Add(Processes[i].MainWindowTitle);
                MessageBox.Show("The window: " + Processes[i].MainWindowTitle + " is open.");
            }
        }
        return OpenWindows;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer to my question. a), this is polling, which should be avoided. b) this will list only the main window of each process.  EnumWindows would list all.